# Slick slider displays only one dot when is dynamic

Tags: jquery, css, laravel-5, plugins

this is my first ever question in this site, I apologize in advance for my level of English (not my first language)

My issue: Im working with Slick slider plugin in Laravel55. This plugin works perfectly with static declaration, but when I try to do it dynamically (using a compacted variable displayed through a foreach loop) it messes with the navigation part, it shows me only one dot and no arrows on the sides.

Looking through similar questions in this site, I've tried to compare the source code between static and dynamic attempts and it generates the same version with a slight indentation difference.

I've checked the charset, verified to load the plugin js after the jQuery and nothing seems to be wrong.

Dynamic

```html
<section class="clients-feedback-area bg-white section_padding_100 clearfix" id="testimonials">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                    <div class="slider slider-for">
                        <!-- Client Feedback Text  -->
                        @foreach($testimonials as $t)
                        <div class="client-feedback-text text-center">
                            <div class="client">
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-description text-center">
                                <p>“ {{$t->comment}} ”</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="star-icon text-center">
                                @for($i=0;$i<$t->rate;$i++)
                                    <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                @endfor
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-name text-center">
                                <h5>{{$t->name}}</h5>
                                <p>{{$t->department}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Client Thumbnail Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="slider slider-nav">
                    @foreach($testimonials as $tp)
                    <div class="client-thumbnail">
                        <img src="{{$tp->pAvatar}}">
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Static

```html
<section class="clients-feedback-area bg-white section_padding_100 clearfix" id="testimonials">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
                    <div class="slider slider-for">
                        <!-- Client Feedback Text  -->
                        <div class="client-feedback-text text-center">
                            <div class="client">
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-description text-center">
                                <p>“ Muchas gracias por todo. Buenisima experiencia. ”</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="star-icon text-center">
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-name text-center">
                                <h5>Dra. Alice Boyle</h5>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Client Feedback Text  -->
                        <div class="client-feedback-text text-center">
                            <div class="client">
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-description text-center">
                                <p>“ Agradezco mucho la atención y excelente estadía. ”</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="star-icon text-center">
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-name text-center">
                                <h5>Carlos Navas</h5>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Client Feedback Text  -->
                        <div class="client-feedback-text text-center">
                            <div class="client">
                                <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-description text-center">
                                <p>“ Fue una experiencia buenísima visitar aquí y una estadía excelente y comoda ¡Gracias!.”</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="star-icon text-center">
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                                <i class="ion-ios-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="client-name text-center">
                                <h5>Liam Reucle</h5>
                                <p></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Client Thumbnail Area -->
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="slider slider-nav">
                        <div class="client-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/icons/icon-user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/icons/icon-user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/icons/icon-user.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-thumbnail">
                            <img src="img/icons/icon-user.png" alt="">
                        </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

For better understanding of my situation and what i'm trying to achieve i've put visualization as follow (I can't insert images, doesn't have 10 points of reputation)

Dynamic behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqS8E.png

Static behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYRnv.png

Sorry for any information i may have skipped
Any help or comments will be appreciated

Comment: I've forgot to mention that the issue only happend when i make dynamic the second part ("Client Thumbnail Area"). I've try using the first half dynamically and the second one static (just for locate the conflict section) and work just fine, the problem is when i add the foreach in the second one.

Comment: yes, as it has no more data to scroll for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i just saw the references you gave and my conclusion:-

1. I think your dynamic view is correct.
2. Add more than 3 data in dynamic testimonials and you will see same behavior.
3. also send `$testimonial` data for more clarification.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer, step two totally works. Could you tell me why it behaves properly with more than 3 data?. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set the `slidesToShow:3` and you have only three testimonials, slick slider adds slider when you have more than 3 testimonials. if you set the `slidesToShow=2` then you will see the slider with dots and arrows and with 2 testimonials at the time.

Hope you will get the answer.